# "pause" is not pausing the execution of script in Octave 5.1.0 in Windows 10

Tags: octave

pause should stop the execution until something happens. But in my case where i have OCTAVE 5.1.0 on OS WINDOWS 10 is not doing its work properly. It does ignore all pause statements in script and execute the whole file.

I am running this program in my installed octave application in command window with GUI.

What may be the problem?

I have tried pause with function brackets 
`pause();`and without function brackets `pause;` but still problem remains same.

```
%do something
plotData(X, y);
fprintf('Press enter to continue.');
pause;
%do something
plotData(X, y);
```

I except that script will first plot data and will stop execution till key is pressed to enable me to analyze data then after key press it would plot another plot with processed data.

But it just plot both plots in fast manner that i could not see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few bugs related to `pause` that have been introduced since version 5.1 and seem that recently have been [fixed](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55943). It will be available in the next version. You can try alternative functions like [kbhit](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/kbhit.html) or switch to a previous version.

Comment: kbhit solved it. Does they give any patches for pause for this version?

Comment: I think you need to recompile octave from c++ source. As a workaround you can create a wrapper function: `function pause();kbit();end;`.

Comment: I would try it.